# Selenium Python - problem with is_displayed() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a Python script that can automate the filling of data into a form. I used Selenium ChromeDriver for this purpose. The execution of the program is not normal, as I happen to encounter an error message every time.

I want the code snippet below to check if a table is present on the website. If yes, execute whatever is below the `if` statement, else execute the `continue` statement.
The problem is that the table that the program is checking **may/may not** be there on the website that I am using.

This is the part of the code that I am concerned about:

```
if(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/center/table/tbody').is_displayed()):
    print("Result Found for Roll No: " + str(rollNo))
    anotherResultLink = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Check Another Result').click()
    result_feeder(rollNo + 1, True)
        
else:
    continue
```

And this is the error message thrown at me every time:

```
Message=Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/center/table/tbody"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)

  Source=E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py
  StackTrace:
  File "E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py", line 61, in admit_card_generator
    if(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/center/table/tbody').is_displayed()):
  File "E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py", line 39, in result_feeder
    admit_card_generator(rno)
  File "E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py", line 64, in admit_card_generator
    result_feeder(rollNo + 1, True)
  File "E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py", line 33, in result_feeder
    admit_card_generator(list_of_roll_nos[i])
  File "E:\Mithun\Python\Website Automator\Website Automator\Website_Automator.py", line 74, in <module>
    result_feeder(20607526, False)
```

Here's the thing that disturbs me about this program. I know for a fact that the `is_displayed()` function returns a boolean value. So, the `if` statement at the beginning of the program checks if the table (which may/may not be there in the website) is present or not.

However, it looks as though Python is refusing to even check the `if` statement, whenever the website that I am using does not have the table. As a result, I am encountering this error.

The question that I have is: How do I force Python to check if a table exists (using the `is_displayed()` function), even though the table does not exist?

Any solutions/workarounds to this problem are greatly appreciated.

P.S.: I am a Grade 12 student.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call is_displayed on an element that does not exist, the element must be present to do so. Basically where it fails with NoSuchElementException is on find_element_by_xpath call.

What you can do is have a try / except.

First import NoSuchElementException:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Then:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/center/table/tbody')
    print("Result Found for Roll No: " + str(rollNo))
    anotherResultLink = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Check Another Result').click()
    result_feeder(rollNo + 1, True)
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your workaround! I have incorporated this in my program with full understanding.